# React JS: How to determine if you are running debug or production

Tags: reactjs

I would like to find out the type of environment (debug/production) my code is running so can set up different services for each `env`. Using code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen most answers when you search the above are for react-native
and after doing small research here is my solution

`console.log("mode is " + process.env.NODE_ENV);`

More details example:

```
if(process.env!.NODE_ENV === "production"){
     // set production urls
     // enable sentry
 }else if(process.env!.NODE_ENV === "development"){
     // set debug urls
 }else{
     // set defaults
}
```